# Why do I get "Project is unviewable" in Excel

Tags: excel-2007, xls

I am trying to look at some vba code, and it says "project is unviewable". Why is this, and how do I change it?

**Details:**

- XLS file extension
- File created Monday, October 14, 1996 6:33:28 PM
- What the code does is disable any passwords on VBA Projects so you can look at it. You click on a button on the sheet, and it opens a little window with a button to disable passwords. It only works for projects that ask for a password when you click on them. By project, I mean the ones in the project explorer in VBE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell without more detail, but the most likely cause is a corrupt file.

**EDIT**

With the file being created in 96, the odds are good that it used the old macro style for vba which is not viewable in newer version of Excel.

If that is the case, you may not have any recourse.

Sometimes, though in the very old files, the macros were actually written in the old macro style, which put the macro code right on the worksheet.  You may want to check for a hidden sheet or hidden cells that might contain old macro code.  Typically this kind of thing was done in Excel 4.0 and earlier.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified what I meant by 'newer version'.  Excel 95, 97, and 2000 should be able to view the 'old stuff'.